# Why won't my clickable div work as a link with this code

Tags: jquery, html

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('.projektet').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<div class='projektet'>
    <h3>".$alias." ".$expertis." ".$other."</h3>
    <h3>".$headline."</h3>
    <p>".$desc."</p>
    <a href='posts.php?id=".$id."'></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.projektet{
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The whole php file

```
<?php
     include("./inc/connect.inc.php");
     $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projekt WHERE sort='startup' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $alias  = $row['användare'];     $id = $row['id'];
    $headline = $row['headline'];
    $desc = $row['beskrivning'];
    $expertis = $row['expertis'];
    $other = $row['annat'];


    echo "<div class='projektet'><h3>".$alias." ".$expertis."".$other."</h3><h3>".$headline."</h3><p>".$desc."</p><a href='posts.php?id=".$id."'></a></div>";
}

?>
```

The alert that I tried directly after the click did not shw, so the problem must be in finding the div, which I think should be no trouble.

Comment: Does url have a valid value?  Or is it that url is undefined?

Comment: It's valid, thanks for ur reply

Comment: I have the same code in another project and it works... I ctrled, pasted it

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Does your file that has the html has the extension `.php`?

Comment: If i put som text between the a tags, the link works

Comment: yes, just writing this to get the length right haha

Comment: Always make sure to validate your code: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Does not work, sorry

Comment: `window.location = url;` should be `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: Do you maybe have to do `.find('a:eq(0)')` instead of just `.find('a')`?

Comment: Your code is correct but the code needs to be in a DOM ready handler (or after the elements on the page that it references). Please show all of the page in your question :)

Comment: None of it works , sorry. TrueBlueAussie, tried that already.

Comment: The jquer y works fine otherwise, so it's really  strange

Comment: What's the processed HTML from the php?  What's the source HTML without the php?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but i put the whole php file in there

Comment: He means: What is the rendered HTML? you can see that by right clicking on the webpage and then clicking on "View source"

Answer (score 1):

The jquery:

```
$('.projektet').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

The HTML/PHP:

```
<div class='projektet'>
    <h3>".$alias." ".$expertis." ".$other."</h3>
    <h3>".$headline."</h3>
    <p>".$desc."</p>
    <a href='posts.php?id=".$id."'></a>
</div>
```

These work just fine, please make sure:

1. Validate your code: [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org)
2. Place your jQuery inside the `ready` function: `$(document).ready(function(){});`

If you want to debug to make sure the href is actually what you want it to be use: `console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href"));`

EDIT: Here is proof this code works just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.projektet').click(function(){
       var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
       alert(url);
      //window.location.href = url;
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='projektet'>
    <h3>headline1</h3>
    <h3>headline2</h3>
    <p>desc</p>
    <a href='posts.php?id=test'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't get i validated.  The problem is however in finding the div as you can see in my update

Comment: If you're placing an `alert('test')` after this line: `$('.projektet').click(function(){` and the alert does not fire then **there's the problem** :)

Comment: Possible causes: 1. `.projektet` class does not exist. 2. it gets injected into the DOM on some event. 3. You have Javascripts errors.

Comment: Why haven't you changed the `window.location` yet?

Comment: Well, you can see the projektet class with css. I've tried $(document).ready () the last one I can't confirm

Comment: I did try that, however you can't see it since I don't put the update code up every time i add something

Comment: The site is not online yet, suppose i could put it up on another, wait a bit

Comment: To much work, I have to put the jquery and everything over aswell

Comment: Well, it should be very simple debugging, remove chunks of your code until it works or rebuild the project from scratch, so you add chunks of code one at a time and see what's causing this.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that but I have already tried building it again, I'll try it on a new page though

Comment: I tried making a new file and just pasting it, and it worked, thanks man!

Comment: If this answers your question please accept it as an answer so we can mark this problem **solved**

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('.projektet').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    window.location.href = 'https://codeclimate.com/';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='projektet'>
  <h3>some text here</h3>
  <h3>Some Text</h3>
  <p> some text</p><a href='https://google.com'></a></div>
```

Comment: Please indicate what you've changed in your answer from the code in the question above.